# Play 2.0 - mapping on a `map` or `for-yield` result in template

Tags: templates, scala, playframework-2.0

I want to perform two sequential `map` operations in Play 2.0 template. I have tried like this:

```
@defining(for(a <- as) yield { doSmthWith(a); doSmthWith2(a) })
    { aaas => aaas.map(_.toString).mkString("|") }   /*CRASH*/
```

which I presume to be equivalent to regular Scala:

```
val aaas = for(a <- as) yield { doSmthWith(a); doSmthWith2(a) }
println(aaas.map(_.toString).mkString("|"))
```

but it crashes there on the first `{` saying `expected start of definition`...

Same thing as if I replace the `for` loop with regular map:

```
@(as.map(a => { doSmthWith(a); doSmthWith2(a) })).map(_.toString).mkString("|"))
```

With the same crash on the first `}` sign. How can I acheive sequentional mapping in a Play template?

**UPDATE:**

The stack - here it is! - right from the console:

```
sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error [expected start of de
finition]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$
11$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(PlayReloader.scala:224) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$
11$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(PlayReloader.scala:224) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$
11.apply(PlayReloader.scala:224) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$
11.apply(PlayReloader.scala:221) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
```

The stack says smth about `Option` but I do not use them anywhere here. Must be some inner workings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
@defining(for (a <- List(1,2,3)) yield { 
   play.api.Logger.debug("a:" + a)
   a*3
}) { as =>
  @(as.mkString("|"))
}
```

Which displays `3|6|9` in the page and prints in the console:

```
[debug] application - a:1
[debug] application - a:2
[debug] application - a:3
```

So my guess is adding the `@` sign in front of the expression as well as putting the opening brace on the same line as the closing paren from defining would make it work (assuming `doSmthWith2(a)` actually returns something else than unit):

```
@defining(for(a <- as) yield { doSmthWith(a); doSmthWith2(a) }) { aaas =>
  @(aaas.map(_.toString).mkString("|"))
}
```